# On pressing a button in panel, why is the data being sent twice, Is there a solution to only send it once?

Tags: capl

If I press a radio button (send data) on Panel, the data is being sent twice or thrice, sometimes once, for the following code:

```
on sysvar RC::send_data

{
systemData.byte(0) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(1) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(2) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(3) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(4) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(5) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(6) = 0x01;

systemData.byte(7) = 0xFF;

output(systemData);
}
```

I need to make it only sent once if I press once, how to achieve it?

And why is the data being sent multiple times randomly?

Expected:

```
Tx : 01010101010101FF
```

Error Outcome:

```
Tx : 01010101010101FF
Tx : 01010101010101FF
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press your button, the sysvar is set to a certain value. You can configure this value in the panel designer in property `Pressed` of the button.

When you release the button, the sysvar is set to a different value. You can configure this value in the panel designer on property `Released` of the button.

Your `on sysvar` event handler gets called once when pressing the button and once when releasing the button.

You could use an `if`-statement in your event handler to only react on certain values of the sysvar.

Comment: **Hii spiller**, **Can you give the example of if-statement you mentioned in your answer, how to make it react to certain values**, you have helped me a lot, please give me with this last one by giving an example,

Comment: Something like `if @sysvar::RC::send_data == 1`. Just consult the CANoe manual, there are plenty of examples on how to work with sysvars.